# if statements on an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm trying to achieve displaying form data dependent on the selection from a previous form. So basically the previous data is collected on a $_POST array basis the original form replicates itself using js and data is sent as an array however on the next page i am trying to display extra form fields based of previous answers its driving me nuts as nothing I'm trying works

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?page=newentry3" id="animaldetails" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="meetandgreet" >

    <div id="container">
        <label for="animalname" class="label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="animalsname[]" class="input" /><br><br>

        <label for="type" class="label">Type</label>
        <select name="type[]" id="type[]" class="custom-select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
            <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
            <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
            <option value="Rodent">Rodent</option>
            <option value="Reptile">Reptile</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label for="breed" class="label">Breed</label>
        <input type="text" name="breed[]" class="input" />
        <br><br>
        <label for="age" class="label">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age[]" class="input" />
        <br><br>
        <label for="medication" class="label">Medication</label>
        <input type="text" name="medication[]" class="input" />
        <br><br>
        <label for="Tendancies" class="label">Tendancies</label>
        <textarea name="tendancies[]" class="input" > </textarea>
        <br><br>         
        <label for="treat" class="label">Treats Allowed </label>
        <select name="treats[]" class="custom-select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label for="feed" class="label2">What To Feed:</label>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none" >
            <label for="hidden" class="label">Feed 1</label>
            <li><input type="text" name="feed1[]" class="input" /></li>
            <label for="hidden" class="label">Feed 2</label>
            <li><input type="text" name="feed2[]" class="input" /></li>
            <label for="hidden" class="label">Feed 3</label>
            <li><input type="text" name="feed3[]" class="input" /></li>
            <label for="hidden" class="label">Feed 4</label>
            <li><input type="text" name="feed4[]" class="input" /></li>
            <label for="hidden" class="label">Feed 5</label>
            <li><input type="text" name="feed5[]" class="input" /></li>
        </ul><br><br>
        <label for="timesday" class="label">How Many Times A Day</label>
        <select name="timesaday[]" class="custom-select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Once">Once</option>
            <option value="Twice">Twice</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name ;?>" name="name" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" name="lastname" />          
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $terms; ?>" name="terms" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" name="number" />                 
        <a href="#" id="add"><img src="images/Add.png"</a>     
        <br/>  

if ($_POST['type']) == 'Horse') {
    echo   "<label for='farrier' class='label'> Farrier Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='farriersname' class='input' /><br>
            <br>         
            <label for='farrier' class='label'> Farriers Telephone</label>  
            <input type='text' name='farriertelephone' class='input'/><br>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I have tried so many different techniques trawled this site for things that might work but nothing appears to I will openly admit I do not thoroughly understand  arrays and how to produce results from them. however what you see above is just the code i started of with before i realized its the array causing the problem

Comment: `if ($_POST['type']) == 'Horse')` is a syntax error.

Comment: What do you want to do?  Be clear about your request

Comment: With `name="type[]"` on the select element, you get an _array_ in `$_POST['type']` - so comparing that to a string value makes no sense to begin with. Since you are using “array syntax” on all your form field names, I would expect to see some sort of _loop_ here first of all, otherwise this makes very little sense in the first place.

Comment: You can clone the div. Try it!

Comment: $_POST['type'] basically holding an array . So you are trying to compare an array to a string. That's will not work.

Comment: sorry should have been more specific (my explanations of things arent that great. basically the form data is posted as an array because the form area is replicated using js however i have failed to include this in the code provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
if($_POST['type'][0]=='Horse'){
    echo "Some code; 
}
```

Comment: But OP wants to know if the type is `Horse` :)

Comment: simply change Dog to Horse; dog has 3 letters onthe other hand horse has 5, so because i am lazy i choose dog :‑D

Comment: as simple as that hmmm maybe i should research more